# MYSQL - Select 2 tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, query, join, inner

Bom dia Pessoal!

Estou com um problema ao realizar uma consulta no MYSQL, sendo que a query que estou utilizando não está exibindo os resultados desejados. Segue o exemplo:

TABELA: `CLIENTES (codigo_cliente, nome, cnpj)`
TABELA: `HISTORICO_CONTATOS (protocolo, codigo_cliente, data, hora)`

Preciso exibir em um grid todas as empresas da TABELA:`CLIENTES` e informar qual foi a data do ultimo contato registrado na TABELA:`HISTORICO_CONTATOS` desses clientes, exemplo:

**TABELA:CLIENTES**

```
CODIGO_CLIENTE---NOME---CNPJ

 - 1---Empresa1---48.989.048/0001-48
 - 2---Empresa2---58.789.048/0001-45
 - 3---Empresa3---38.889.048/0001-62 
 - 4---Empresa4---98.289.048/0001-02

**TABELA:HISTORICO_CONTATOS**

PROTOCOLO---CODIGO_CLIENTE---DATA---HORA

 - 1001---3---10/01/2016---09:10
 - 1002---1---13/01/2016---08:30
 - 1003---1---23/02/2016---11:15
 - 1004---2---23/02/2016---11:16
 - 1005---1---25/02/2016---08:16
 - 1006---3---29/02/2016---16:16
 - 1007---1---03/03/2016---07:30

**EXIBIÇÃO DESEJADA**

CODIGO_CLIENTE---NOME---DATA---HORA

 - 4---EMPRESA4---00/00/0000---00:00
 - 2---EMPRESA2---23/02/2016---11:16
 - 3---EMPRESA3---29/02/2016---16:16
 - 1---EMPRESA1---03/03/2016---07:30
```

Como havia dito, preciso de uma query que mostre todos os clientes(sem duplicidade) e na linha do cliente informe qual foi a data do ultimo contato deste cliente, sendo assim para os demais. Se não houver contato, ele tem que exibir o cliente mesmo assim, sendo que a data ficaria em branco.

Atualmente a query esta da seguinte maneira:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.cli_codigo, c.cli_nome, c.cli_bairro, c.cli_cidade, c.cli_vinculo, c.cli_ultimostatus, MAX(h.tel_datacontato) as tel_datacontato
            FROM cli_clientes c INNER JOIN tel_historico h ON c.cli_codigo = h.cli_codigo {$where}
            GROUP BY c.cli_codigo ORDER BY {$order_by} {$limit}";
```

Alguem pode ajudar

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de `INNER JOIN` utilize `LEFT JOIN`. O `INNER` obriga que tenha registro nas duas tabelas, o `LEFT` leva em consideração imperativamente a tabela de referência.

Sua `query` ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT c.cli_codigo,
       c.cli_nome,
       c.cli_bairro,
       c.cli_cidade,
       c.cli_vinculo,
       c.cli_ultimostatus,
       MAX(h.tel_datacontato) as tel_datacontato
  FROM cli_clientes c
  LEFT JOIN tel_historico h ON c.cli_codigo = h.cli_codigo
 {$where}
 GROUP BY c.cli_codigo
 ORDER BY {$order_by}
 {$limit}
```

**EDIT 1**

Com `subquery` para melhorar a performance:

```
SELECT c.cli_codigo,
       c.cli_nome,
       c.cli_bairro,
       c.cli_cidade,
       c.cli_vinculo,
       c.cli_ultimostatus,
       (SELECT MAX(h.tel_datacontato)
          FROM tel_historico h
         WHERE c.cli_codigo = h.cli_codigo) as tel_datacontato
  FROM cli_clientes c
 {$where}
 ORDER BY {$order_by}
 {$limit}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição Sorack, vou inserir as modificações que você fez e em breve informarei o resultado, contribuindo assim com dúvidas semelhantes que surgirem.

Comment: Fiz os teste e infelizmente não deu certo, só para reforçar:

- Preciso que apareça todos os clientes da TABELA:CLIENTES, independente de ter ou não contato registrado para um determinado cliente na TABELA: HISTORICO.

-Ao aparecer todos os clientes, mostrar qual a data do ultimo contato feita para este cliente (Esta informação se encontra na TABELA:HISTORICO), se não tiver nenhum contato, não interfere na exibição do cliente, devendo aparecer apena em branco a data.

Quando insiro RIGHT JOIN, ele mostra os clientes mas que não tem registro de contato, não aparece na lista de clientes.

Comment: É left join que você tem que usar. E retira também o limit e o where pra mostrar todos.

Comment: O Limit e o Where não estão afetando no resultado, mesmo sem eles, as empresas que não possuem registro de contato, não aparecem na lista

Comment: Vc colocou left join ao invés de inner?

Comment: Sobrecarrega muito o processamento do servidor, teria uma sugestão para montar o banco de dados para que não ficasse pesado desta forma?

Comment: Verifique agora com o segundo exemplo